# GroupBox in ContentControl - support for IDataErrorInfo implemented by the content bound to the ContentControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, validation

I have a ViewModel that represents multiple options and implements `IDataErrorInfo`. This ViewModel is only valid if at least one of these options is selected. It is bound to a `ContentControl`. A `DataTemplate` is used to visualize the ViewModel as a `GroupBox` containing an `ItemsControl`. Another `DataTemplate` visualizes each option as a `CheckBox`.

What do I have to do, to make the `ContentControl` work together with `IDataErrorInfo` and check the validity when a check box is checked or unchecked?

---

Some code:

Binding:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding GeneralInvoiceTypes, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                Margin="0,0,5,0" />
```

Data templates:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:MultipleOptionsViewModel}">
  <GroupBox Header="{Binding Title}">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Options}" />
  </GroupBox>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:OptionViewModel}">
  <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"
            Content="{Binding Name}"
            Margin="6,3,3,0" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError"
             Value="true">
      <Setter Property="ToolTip"
              Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
  <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate>
        <Grid>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="90*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <Border BorderBrush="Red"
                  BorderThickness="1"
                  CornerRadius="2.75"
                  Grid.Column="0">
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder Grid.Column="0" />
          </Border>
          <TextBlock Foreground="Red"
                     Grid.Column="1"
                     Margin="0"
                     FontSize="12"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                     x:Name="txtError">
            *
          </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: can you post your bindings please. i assume that ValidatesOnDataErrors=True is set in your bindings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answers given, I solved it like this:

1. Change the `DataTemplate` of the `MultipleOptionsViewModel` to bind the `Options` property with `ValidatesOnDataErrors=True`:

   ```
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:MultipleOptionsViewModel}">
       <GroupBox Header="{Binding Title}">
           <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Options,
                                       ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
       </GroupBox>
   </DataTemplate>
   ```
2. Change the error style to target `ItemsControl` instead of `ContentControl`.
3. Make sure that `MultipleOptionsViewModel` raises a PropertyChanged for `"Options"` when one of the child options is checked or unchecked
4. Make sure that `MultipleOptionsViewModel` reacts to the column `"Options"` in its implementation if [`IDataErrorInfo.Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.item.aspx), i.e. in its indexer.

This solution has the benefit, that it uses the default behavior of `IDataErrorInfo`, i.e. the consumer of this ViewModel doesn't need handle it any special.

I know that this solution is not 100% equivalent to that I asked about in the question - the error template is now displayed *inside* the group box instead of around it, but that's something I can live with.

Answer (score 3):

> What do I have to do, to make the ContentControl work together with
>   IDataErrorInfo and check the validity when a check box is checked or
>   unchecked?

Adding a bit to *Rachels* answer.

This problem would be easier to solve with Asynchronous data Validation but unfortunately, that isn't available before [WPF 4.5 is released](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#INotifyDataErrorInfo).

`Content` is binding to `GeneralInvoiceTypes` in `MainViewModel`. Since we can't do Asynchronous data Validation, then `PropertyChanged` has to be raised for `GeneralInvoiceTypes` for the validation to occur. This would work but I would take the approach that *Rachel* suggested and introduce another property called `IsValid` in *MultipleOptionsViewModel*

The binding to `IsValid` can be done from `Tag` (or an attached property) to `GeneralInvoiceTypes.IsValid`. We would also have to be notified in *MultipleOptionsViewModel* when `IsChecked` is changed in any of the `Options`. This can be done by using a command binding in the `CheckBoxes` for example.

So some changes along the following lines would be required.

*I also uploaded a sample project with this implemented here:* https://www.dropbox.com/s/fn8e4n4s68wj3vk/ContentControlValidationTest.zip?dl=0

*ContentControl*

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=GeneralInvoiceTypes}"
                Tag="{Binding Path=GeneralInvoiceTypes.IsValid,
                              ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
```

*OptionViewModel DataTemplate*

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:OptionViewModel}">
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"
                Content="{Binding Name}"
                Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentControl}},
                                Path=DataContext.IsValidCheckCommand}"
                Margin="6,3,3,0" />
</DataTemplate>
```

*MultipleOptionsViewModel*

```
private ICommand m_isValidCheckCommand;
public ICommand IsValidCheckCommand
{
    get
    {
        return m_isValidCheckCommand ??
            (m_isValidCheckCommand = new RelayCommand(param => IsValidCheck()));
    }
}

private void IsValidCheck()
{
    IsValid = CheckIsValid();
}

private bool CheckIsValid()
{
    foreach (OptionViewModel option in Options)
    {
        if (option.IsChecked == true)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private bool m_isValid;
public bool IsValid
{
    get { return m_isValid; }
    set
    {
        m_isValid = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsValid");
    }
}

public string this[string columnName]
{
    get
    {
        if (columnName == "IsValid")
        {
            if (IsValid == false)
            {
                return "At least 1 Option must be selected";
            }
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the sample project. Unfortunately, I can't split the bounty, that's why it goes to Rachel - her explanation helped me understand the underlying problem.

Answer (score 1):

Does the class containing the`GeneralInvoiceTypes` property implement `IDataErrorInfo`?

Setting `ValidatesOnDataErrors=True` will show validation errors for the DataContext that contains the bound property, so in this case it is validing `ParentViewModel.GetValidationError("GeneralInvoiceTypes")`, and not `GeneralInvoiceTypes.GetValidationError()`

In this case, you can either add `IDataErrorInfo` to your `ParentViewModel` and validate the `GeneralInvoiceTypes` property by returning it's Validation Error like this:

```
public string GetValidationError(string propertyName)
{
    if (propertyName == "GeneralInvoiceTypes")
        return GeneralInvoiceTypes.GetValidationError();

    return null;
}
```

or you can create an `IsValid` property on `GeneralInvoiceTypes` which returns `GetValidationError() == null` and base your validation Trigger off of `{Binding IsValid}` rather then `Validation.HasError`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The explanation why it is not working helped me a lot. That's why I awarded the bounty. However, I am trying to find a cleaner solution to this problem, that's why I am not yet accepting your answer.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Both options (adding `IDataErrorInfo` to your `ParentViewModel`, or adding an `IsValid` property to your `MultipleOptionsViewModel` class) are acceptable ways of doing this. Which one you choose depends on which makes more sense for your project, although either one will work.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In my opinion, both options are a bit leaky. Option one (`IDataErrorInfo`): Every `ParentViewModel` (there can be multiple) that uses `MultipleOptionsViewModel` needs to implement this special handling. Option two (`IsValid` property): Every View that displays the `MultipleOptionsViewModel` needs to use that "special binding" with `IsValid` to make sure that it works. This means: Every time the `MultipleOptionsViewModel` is used a chance of failure is introduced. Please see my answer. This encapsulates this in two distinct places: The VM itself and the DataTemplate.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I was thinking that option 1 would only need to be implemented if the View needed to validate the `MultipleOptionsViewModel`, and Option 2 is fairly standard. I often use an `IsValid` property on my models, especially if my I wish to base a `RelayCommand.CanExecute` on `Model.IsValid`. Glad you found a way that worked for you though :)

Comment: As the sole purpose of the `MultipleOptionsViewModel` is to ensure that at least one option is selected, every VM that uses it, would need to validate it. `IsValid` is not a problem per se, in fact, my `MultipleOptionsViewModel` already has one, but the need to remember to use it in the binding every time I want to visualize it, is the part I don't like. I like my code base to be designed in a way that makes it hard for me to use my objects in the wrong way :-)